# Size of a table for records by date.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get the size of a table in terms of records before a certain date. Meaning I want to know what the size of the table with records that are 2 years and older.

Comment: size in Bytes or record count? Also, do you have audit information of deleted records? Do you have a time stamp of every record?

Comment: Does the table have a column that indicates how old the record is?

Comment: Yes there is indication of a date column that explains how old the record is.

Comment: Yes it would be size in bytes. And I don't know what you mean by audit information of deleted records.

Comment: @user2684009 I mean, maybe the table have 1M rows 2 years ago, but someone deleted 250K records in the mid time. So the measure you do now (750K) is not correct unless you add information of deleted records

Comment: No I don't think this information is deleted. and there is no audit of the information that is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to get only size based on partial rows in the table, you can sum up length of each column, this will be approximate

Assuming your date column is createdDate

```
select SUM(datalength(col1))+SUM(datalength(col2))+.. from tableName
WHERE datediff(year, createdDate, getdate()) > 2
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @user2684009, you can use my query.

Comment: I am trying to understand what information this would provide me. So this would provide me the size of each column based on what I choose to filter and I can sum the number of columns to get the size of the record. Now is this size in Kbs, MBs, Bytes, etc?

Comment: @user2684009, it is in bytes

Answer (score 0):

You can get the amount of database pages currently allocated for the table and adjust the value to the amount of rows it had 2 years ago:

```
select sq.SchemaName, sq.TableName, sq.IndexName, sq.IndexId, sq.Rows, sq.TableSize,
    sum(sq.total_pages) as [TotalPages],
    round(cast(sum(sq.total_pages) as money) / 128, 3) as [ObjectSizeMB]
from (  
    select object_schema_name(t.object_id) as [SchemaName], t.name as [TableName], i.Name as [IndexName], i.Index_Id as [IndexId], pt.Rows,
        au.total_pages,
        round(cast(sum(au.total_pages) over(partition by t.object_id) as money) / 128, 3) as [TableSize]
    from sys.tables t
        inner join sys.partitions pt on t.object_id = pt.object_id
        inner join sys.indexes i on pt.object_id = i.object_id and pt.index_id = i.index_id
        inner join sys.allocation_units au on au.container_id = case
            when au.type in (1, 3) then pt.hobt_id
            when au.type = 2 then pt.partition_id
        end
    where t.type in ('U', 'V')
    ) sq
where sq.IndexId < 2
group by sq.TableName, sq.IndexName, sq.IndexId, sq.Rows, sq.TableSize, sq.SchemaName
order by sq.tablesize desc, sq.SchemaName, sq.TableName, TotalPages desc;
```

The `ObjectSizeMB` column shows space taken by an object (heap, clustered or nonclustered index), while `TableSize` contains subtotals of these values for the entire table (or indexed view). Depending on your definition of "table size", you can use either of them. And if you want to see nonclustered indices in the list, the outer `where sq.IndexId < 2` should be commented out.

Should give you a good starting point.

Comment: How would I adjust the value of the amount of rows that were there 2 years ago?

Comment: @user2684009, the `Rows` column contains current amount of rows in the table / index. Separately from this, you can query the amount of rows that satisfy your "were there 2 years ago" condition. The rest is trivial.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand how that query would look like.

Comment: `select (select count(*) from dbo.YourTable where DateCol <= dateadd(year, -2, sysdatetime())) / cast(sq.Rows as money) * sq.TableSize from (...` and so on.